# Problem starting a Workflow on a list item Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am an administrator of my site. I created the forms under my domain account (personal) that is part of the Owners group.

We recently moved to a new Domain. There were many issues with permissions, but this one I really need help with.

Each day I come it is the same thing. I can no longer start one of my List Worfklows on a List Item.  It gives me this error:

A form template (.xsn) file cannot be accessed. You may not have the required permissions to open the file.

I looked up the actual error in the log and it says "most likely permissions issue".

I checked the workflow in Designer, where I originally had create it using my OLD domain account.  The workaround seems to be to make a slight change to the workflow (incidental) and then recompile/publish.

I can't go through this EVERY DAY! Is there a permanent solution???  Why would it be the workaround doesn't "hold"?